# Invoke the click handler of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to invoke the click of a button programatically using JavaScript. My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() { autoload(); });

function autoload() {

    var button = $("#button");
    var video = $("#video");
    var evnt = button["onclick"];

    // Set the click handler of the button
    button.click(function () {
        video.get(0).play();
    });

    // Call the button's click handler
    if (typeof button.onclick == "function") {
        button.onclick.apply(button);
    }
}
```

But for some reason this is not working, the click handler is not called.

Answer (score 4):

[Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) in jQuery are [different](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js) than native DOM events.

You should use `button.click()` or `button.trigger("click")`.